# Core plot Image not scaling in ios7

Tags: ios, graph, core-plot

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_16.png"];
    CPTImage *background = [CPTImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:image.scale];
    CPTBorderedLayer *imageLayer = [[CPTBorderedLayer alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 16)];
    imageLayer.fill = [CPTFill fillWithImage:background];
    CPTAxisLabel *iconLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithContentLayer:imageLayer];
    iconLabel.offset = 8;
    iconLabel.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(location+0.5);
```

Image not scaling in ios7.Please give me solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does `tick_16.png` also have an @2x version (`tick_16@2x.png`) available in the app? Does the scaling problem happen on Retina devices, non-Retina devices, or both?

Comment: Thanks Eric Skroch, i had problem with retina devices only. I forgot to add @2x image. Now tis working fine. Thanks for your help...